# $_POST not working in PHP

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head><title>HEllo</title></head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="address">
<input type ="submit" name = "s" value = "Employee">
<?php
$link =mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die("Failed");
mysql_select_db("gagan",$link) or die("database not exists");

if($_POST['s']=="Employee")
{
print "g";
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
print "hi";
$update = "update emp set name = $name, address=$address where id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($update,$link);
print "Hello";
if($result)
{
    print "Updated";
}   
else{   
    print "$update";
}
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run this code it produce an notice and the above code is not working.

> Notice: Undefined index: s in C:\wamp\www\1.php on line 12

What's the problem in my code can anybody tell me?

Comment: Did you POST the `s` variable?

Comment: try to delete unnecessary spaces in <input type="submit" name="s" value="Employee">

Comment: Side note: how comes you are only using `mysql_real_escape_string()` in one of the three values?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the form tag.

```
<form action="yourform.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: I suspect this omission (and the coding style in general) shows a misunderstanding of how HTML forms work in general. He's probably expecting the value to be available in PHP right after the HTML tag where it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that array member is set first. Try using the result of `isset($_POST['s'])` to ensure it is set before trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the form tage with the method set to post.

ie

Answer (score 0):

The main problem (in addition to the missing form tag) is that the program flow continues to the part that tries to save the data even when the form hasn't been submitted yet. You must check that the form has been submitted before trying to save the data, or even easier would be if you moved the data saving part to its own script.

You also have an invalid SQL query but that's another matter :)